# Is there a specific name for a concentric dots pattern in a circle?

Tags: shapes, patterns, terminology, product-design

There are examples of it in many industrial products, like the radio speaker below (the circle pattern in the top left corner):

[image: 1959 Portable Transistor Radio and Phonograph (model TP 1) (MOMA Collection) Dieter Rams]

[1959 Portable Transistor Radio and Phonograph (model TP 1) (MOMA Collection) Dieter Rams](https://www.flickr.com/photos/34019036@N05/5211646175/in/photostream/)

Comment: Not that product design is not **graphic** design. Radial pattern, although in your example case the pattern justr grows in elemnt number as you go further. But it is still a radial pattern-

Answer (score 1):

**Speaker Grill**

- Concentric dots Braun T49 Speaker Grill

[image]

- Fibonacci Spiral Speaker Grill

[image]

- Concentric lines speaker grill

[image]

Comment: I don't think "speaker grill" is part of the name of these patterns though...

Comment: While covers or grills for speakers are commonly made by drilling holes in this pattern, I was curious if any particular name is used in the trade (if any) for the pattern itself, independent of any particular application.

Comment: they really are called just grills or screens. The patterns are endless, but "concentric circle, waffle, hex" etc are the patterns, some of which @danielillo points out. These patterns will not be specific to loudspeaker design, but rather screen/grill design. They are going to be adjectival or purely descriptive.